# Can I get results from Search.List for a specific region via the YouTube API V3

Tags: youtube-api

When someone does a search on YouTube in India, they see different search results than someone who does a search for the same term in the United States.

We need to know how to see what someone from India sees when they search using the YouTube API.

Have tried setting regionCode to "IN" but it seems to make absolutely no difference.

We have tried setting the UserIP property to an IP Address in India before calling Search.List

Our servers are in the United States but we need to see what gets returned by someone in India. Thank you for your help!

Comment: To my knowledge "regionCode" should work. It depends on what your searching. The following both requests are giving different results. `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=SNL&type=video&regionCode=IN&key={YOUR_API_KEY}` and `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=SNL&type=video&regionCode=SG&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Comment: Apparently a bug has been reported to Google already: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6913

I tried your examples and they returned the same results.